# How to stretch a table over multiple pages

Tags: pagination, latex

I have a Table (multiple rows, multiple columns, see below ) that is longer than one page. 
How can I tell LaTeX to continue on the next page.

- Adding a \newpage didn't work
- Manually 'ending' and 'reopening' the table works, but is very tedious, since the table will be many pages long.

  ```
  \begin{tabular}{lp{13cm}} 
      AAAAAAAAAA  & FOOBAR FOOBAR FOOBAR FOOBAR FOOBAR\\
      BBBBBBBBBB  & FOOBAR FOOBAR FOOBAR FOOBAR FOOBAR\\
      CCCCCCCCCC  & FOOBAR FOOBAR FOOBAR FOOBAR FOOBAR\\

      ...

      ZZZZZZZZZ  &  FOOBAR FOOBAR FOOBAR FOOBAR FOOBAR\\
   \end{tabular}
  ```

Comment: In future: See tex.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You should `\usepackage{longtable}`.

- PDF Documentation of the package: ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/tools/longtable.pdf
- Tutorial with examples can be found [here](http://users.sdsc.edu/~ssmallen/latex/longtable.html).

Comment: What if you are using the `tabularx` environment and have the same problem?

Comment: To answer my own comment, I just found that the `longtabu` environment in the `tabu` package is basically a redefinition of the `longtable` environment, which allows the same kind of syntax that `tabularx` uses for defining "flexible columns".